# How to use different php version on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, ssh, apache-2.4

I have a main webpage that uses `php v5.6`, now we're integrating a project into a subdomain that need `php v7.1`

```
/var/www/html/mainpage.com

/var/www/html/subdomain.mainpage.com
```

The server is a vps with no panel, so i must do everything via ssh, if i check `php -v` i get `PHP 7.1.11-1...` so i gues php 7 is available, but when i check with  `echo phpInfo();` it says its running `php v5.6`,

How can i tell the server to only run `php v7.1` on  the subdomain project?

**i am new to this so do not asume i should know something.**

Comment: If you're using Apache, chances are PHP is installed there via mod_php. `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1` may do the trick. Make sure you do it on a test server first, in case it breaks things.

Comment: This might be the question your direct towards your VPS provider as there are a number of ways to set this up, some of which will require the VPS providers' assistance, especially if you can't edit the apache configuration directly.